# Matplotlib, usetex=True breaks wrap=True

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I want to build a figure with a wrapping caption below the figure. I would like to have wrapping text using Latex features. After several unsuccessful attempts, I went back to the example provided by the documentation and added the latex requirements, once for one text using `usetex=True` and once for all of them using `rcParams.update`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# plt.rcParams.update({
#     "text.usetex": True,
#     "font.family": "Helvetica"
# })


fig = plt.figure()
plt.axis([0, 10, 0, 10])
t = ("This is a really long string that I'd rather have wrapped so that it "
     "doesn't go outside of the figure, but if it's long enough it will go "
     "off the top or bottom!")
#plt.text(4, 1, t, ha='left', rotation=15, wrap=True, usetex = True)
plt.text(4, 1, t, ha='left', rotation=15, wrap=True)
plt.text(6, 5, t, ha='left', rotation=15, wrap=True)
plt.text(5, 5, t, ha='right', rotation=-15, wrap=True)
plt.text(5, 10, t, fontsize=18, style='oblique', ha='center',
         va='top', wrap=True)
plt.text(3, 4, t, family='serif', style='italic', ha='right', wrap=True)
plt.text(-1, 0, t, ha='left', rotation=-15, wrap=True)
#plt.savefig("usetex.png") # used with the line 22 uncommented
#plt.savefig("rcParamsUpdate.png") # used with the line 11-14 uncommented
plt.savefig("example.png") # used without latex

plt.show()
```

Here are links to the examples:

"usetex.png" - lower right textbox doesn't wrap:

[image]

"rcParamsUpdate.png" - no textbox wraps:

[image]

"example.png" - all text wrapping properly:

[image]

This leads me to believe that whenever I try to use `wrap=True` and latex, the wrapping for this text doesn't work.
Sadly I can't provide insight into *why* this happens. Does someone have a suggestion what I could do, except for breaking my lines by hand? Thank you!

I use python: 3.8.13
and matplotlib: 3.5.2